# Changing computer name

Tags: gedit, hostname

Can someone tell me how to change the computer name on a pc, I've tried to edit the `/etc/hostname` file but it won't allow me access to save the amended file, thought the user the system created was the administrator obviously not.

Thanks

Comment: Run in a Terminal: sudo nano /etc/hostname when asked enter your password, then edit the displayed text.

Answer (score 7):

> Changing the hostname or computer name in ubuntu

Edit /etc/hostname and change to the new value, for example name we are using **hostname Ubuntu**

```
sudo nano /etc/hostname
Ubuntu
```

Edit /etc/hosts and change the old 127.0.1.1 line to your new hostname

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   ubuntu.local    ubuntu   # change to your new hostname/fqdn
```

**Note** : Edit /etc/hosts and change the old 127.0.1.1 line to your new hostname (if you dont do this, you wont be able to use sudo anymore. If you hav e already done it, press ESC on the grub menu, choose recovery, and edit your host file to the correct settings)

Now after a reboot, your hostname will be the new one you chose

If you want to apply the change **without a reboot**,

```
sudo service hostname restart
```

OR

```
 sudo /etc/init.d/hostname restart
```

**Note** : Above command to make the change active. The hostname saved in this file (/etc/hostname) will be preserved on system reboot (and will be set using the same script we used hostname).

Answer (score 4):

You need to change 2 files and can use the following commands for that...

```
pkexec nano /etc/hostname
pkexec nano /etc/hosts
```

Only change the name; nothing else.

Comment: says cannot open display?

Comment: Are you using ssh to connect to the system? That message means that there is no X server active(?)